# change value dictionary by index

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary dico like this :

```
id_OS (keys)  :  List of pages(values)
0 :      [A, B]
1 :      [C, D, E]
2 :      [F, B]
3 :      [G, A, B]
```

I would like to change it to this form

```
 id_OS  :  List of index id_pages 

0 :      [0, 1]
1 :      [2, 3, 4]
2 :      [5, 1]
3 :      [6, 0, 1]
```

I try  this code, but i didnt got the correct index of values :

```
dico = dict(zip(range(len(dico)), zip(range(len(dico.values())))))
```

Any idea please to do it

Thanks

Comment: for each key read the `Values` as an array. Now for each element in Values Array, subtract ASCII value of  character 'A' from the ASCII value of  current element. Store this value back to the array. Reassign this array to the key.

Comment: Would you mind sharing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
letters = {0: ['A', 'B'], 1: ['C', 'Z']}
for key in letters:
    new_list = []
    for i in letters[key]:
        i = i.lower()
        new_list.append(ord(i) - 97)
    letters[key] = new_list
```

I subtracted 97 instead of 96 (The reason why 96 is subtracted is well explained in this post: [Convert alphabet letters to number in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4528982/convert-alphabet-letters-to-number-in-python)) because it seems like you want everything to be shifted so that A is 0 not 1 like it would usually be.

Output:

```
{0: [0, 1], 1: [2, 25]}
```

Comment: You should probably explain how 96 and 97 are relevant, and how OP went wrong, but other than that, good answer.

Comment: @catasaurus tank you! but in reality they are not letter but random integer..

Answer (score 0):

through your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71364728/18344512) I see that you could simplefy your task. I would change data['PageId'] type into categories and passed categories codes to the dictionary. Something like this:

```
data['codes'] = data['PageId'].astype('category').cat.codes
```

then change this line in your code:

```
dico[tup].append(row['PageId'])
```

into this:

```
dico[tup].append(row['codes'])
```